# How to send files from two different location with one TCP-Server?

Tags: file, delphi, tcp

How to send files from two  different locations via only one TCP-Server, I managed to send files from one location only. 
This the code to send from one directory ...

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  fs: TFileStream;
  fn: string;
  sr: TSearchRec;
  I: integer;
begin
  I := 0;
  if FindFirst('C:/*.jpg', faAnyFile, sr) = 0 then
  begin
    with StringGrid1 do
    begin
      ListBox1.Items.Add('C:/' + sr.Name);
      while FindNext(sr) = 0 do
      begin
        ListBox1.Items.Add('C:/' + sr.Name);
        Inc(I);
        if I = 7 then
          Break;
      end;
      FindClose(sr);
      idTCPClient1.Connect;
      for fn in ListBox1.Items do
      begin
        fs := TFileStream.Create(fn, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
        try
          idTCPClient1.IOHandler.WriteLn(ExtractFileName(fn));
          idTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write(fs, 0, True);
          idUDPClient1.Send(lbLatitude.Text + ',' + lbLongitude.Text);
        Finally
          fs.Free;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking here. What specific problem are you having with the code you posted?

Comment: the code for sending files from 1 directory, i need it to send files from tow different directories ?

Comment: You're sending files based on the 8 items you put in the listbox. If those 8 files are in the same directory, then you're only sending files from one directory on purpose. If you want it to be different, put items into the listbox that are in different directories. Your code is what is putting the filenames into the list box, and you're only sending those files.

Comment: A common mistake that less experienced coders make is to put all the code into one big function. This is a classic example. You've got string grid, list box, file enumeration, stream opening and network comms. All mixed into one big gloop. Break it into small pieces that do specific tasks. Write a function that transfers a stream, say. Deal with preparing that stream elsewhere. Make it easy to test the code.

Comment: can i put files in a listbox from tow different Directories, example? ? sorry for noobs question

Comment: You can put any text into a list box that you want. It's up to you what files you list there. If those files aren't the ones you want, then add the ones you do want. Directories have nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do (without completely re-writing your code, like DavidH suggested) is simply fill your ListBox with paths from all of the different directories that you want, eg:

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  fs: TFileStream;
  fn: string;
  sr: TSearchRec;
  I : integer;
begin
  I := 0;
  if FindFirst('C:/*.jpg', faAnyFile, sr) = 0 then
  begin
    repeat
      ListBox1.Items.Add('C:/' + sr.Name);
      Inc(I);
      if I = 7 then Break;
    until FindNext(sr) <> 0;
    FindClose(sr);
  end;

  if I < 7 then
  begin
    if FindFirst('C:/Some Other Folder/*.jpg', faAnyFile, sr) = 0 then
    begin
      repeat
        ListBox1.Items.Add('C:/Some Other Folder/' + sr.Name);
        Inc(I);
        if I = 7 then Break;
      until FindNext(sr) <> 0;
      FindClose(sr);
    end;
  end;

  idTCPClient1.Connect;
  for fn in ListBox1.Items do
  begin
    fs := TFileStream.Create(fn, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
    try
      IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.WriteLn(ExtractFileName(fn));
      IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write(fs, 0, True);
      ...
    finally
      fs.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```